# How to bind dropdownlist from splist column with choice field using C#

Tags: splist

Here is my list with name "Department" and name,mobile these are my column name and i want to add to my dropdown list only mobile number(column)plz help me ...

```
    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://alluser/Staffs");
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    SPList list = web.Lists["Department"];
    SPFieldChoice filed = (SPFieldChoice)list.Fields["mobile"];
    drop_dept.DataSource = filed.Choices;
    drop_dept.DataBind();
```

**that code not showing any thing to my dropdownlist....**
can any one gave me sol.

Answer (score 1):

I used the same Code and it worked for me. Check your Choice Field I think You Might forgot to add Choices in your Choice Field.

I used Code from [Shobha's Blog](http://way2explore.blogspot.in/2010/02/bind-dropdown-list-with-sharepoint.html) and it is also working.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
        Guid siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
         {
             using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
             {
                 using (SPWeb objSPWeb = site.RootWeb)
                 {
                     SPList objSPList = objSPWeb.Lists["Department"];

                     SPFieldChoice field = (SPFieldChoice)objSPList.Fields["mobile"];
                     DropDownList1.DataSource = field.Choices;
                     DropDownList1.DataBind();
                 }
             }
         });
```

very similar to yours, as i think yours work, maybe its the user your using? so iv wrapped it into a runwithelevatedpriv

hope it helps :)

Comment: I dont know why iv been marked down as its perfectly fine to wrap a spsecurity as the user the op could be using could not have access to the list that they want to get the mobile colum from!

Comment: if my answer is correct please mark it as correct so others know the answer two when they come up with the same issue :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found that for some reason the following code:

```
drop_dept.DataSource = filed.Choices;
drop_dept.DataBind();
```

always makes `drop_dept.SelectedItem` refer to the first element on the list regardless the item actually selected.

Replacing it with:

```
foreach (string choice in filed.Choices)
{
    drop_dept.Items.Add(choice);
}
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I used for a solution for SP 2013 where IQSReportNames is my SharePoint list name and the title field (from that sharepoint list) is what goes into the drop down:

```
reportName = new DropDownList();

Guid siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
{
     using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
     {
          SPList oList = web.Lists["IQSReportNames"];
          string url = string.Empty;
          foreach (SPListItem oItem in oList.Items)
          {
               reportName.Items.Add(new ListItem(oItem.Title));
          }
     }
 }
```